# Checking your own IP Address

Tags: c#, .net

I'm novice programmer and Ive tried to check my own IP address. The problem is I don't like copy paste thing and I really need to understand what I'm doing. With some help of Google I think I understand most of it, but still there are some not clear things. I would be very thankful for explanation. Things I don't get are pointed in comments. Also I it would be nice someone can check if my thinking (in comments) is correct.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
/*
 * The System.Net namespace provides a simple programming interface for many of the protocols used on networks today. 
 * The WebRequest and WebResponse classes form the basis of what are called pluggable protocols, an implementation of network services that enables you to develop applications that use Internet resources without worrying about the specific details of the individual protocols.
 * Classes in the System.Net namespace can be used to develop Windows Store apps or desktop apps. When used in a Windows Store app, classes in the System.Net namespace are affected by network isolation feature, part of the application security model used by the Windows Developer Preview. 
 * The appropriate network capabilities must be enabled in the app manifest for a Windows Store app for the system to allow network access by a Windows Store app. For more information, see the Network Isolation for Windows Store Apps.
*/
using System.IO;
//The System.IO namespace contains types that allow reading and writing to files and data streams, and types that provide basic file and directory support.
public class PokazIP : MonoBehaviour {

    public string GetLocalIP()
    {
        string localIP = "?";//New variable of string type
        IPHostEntry host;//New variable of IPHostEntry type learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        //IPHostEntry -> Provides a container class for Internet host address information. One of its properties is AddressList.
        //AddressList -> Gets or sets a list of IP addresses that are associated with a host.
        //Learn more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.addresslist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        /*Dns. a class of System.Net(System.Net.Dns) which provides simple domain name resolution functionality
        learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        .GetHostEntry(hostNameOrAddress -> Type: System.String -> The host name or IP address to resolve.) 
         * method of Dns class which resolves a host name or IP address to an IPHostEntry instance. (Actually I dont really understand this discription.)
         * Return Value -> Type: System.Net.IPHostEntry -> An IPHostEntry instance that contains address information about the host specified in hostNameOrAddress.
         * learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        .GetHostName() method of Dns class which gets the host name of the local computer.
         * Return Value -> Type: System.String -> A string that contains the DNS host name of the local computer.
         * learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        */
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)//**New variable called ip of type IPAddress. host.AddressList is made of IPAddress objects???**
        //Properties of IPAdress: Address and AddressFamily
        //learn more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")//**Whats InterNetwork? Why do we look for that in ip?**
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();//obvious
                break;//**so if it finds "InterNetwork" it is not looking further 'coz its not needed?**
            }
        }
        return localIP;//returns IP
    }
    public string GetPublicIP()
        /*
         * This funcion is using checkip server to tell you yours IP.
         * I guess it is because for some reason we cant do it from our computer. Why?
         */
    {
        string direction = "";//New variable of type string
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        /*
         * WebRequest.Create Method (String)
         * Initializes a new WebRequest instance for the specified URI scheme.
         * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
         * WebRequest is a class of System.Net
         * Makes a request to a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI). This is an abstract class. <- I dont really get it to many unknown things :S
         * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
         */
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        /*
         * Why "using"?
         * WebResponse is a class of System.Net
         * Provides a response from a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI). This is an abstract class. <- I dont really get it to many unknown things :S
         * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
         * GetResponse() is a method of WebRequest
         * When overridden in a descendant class, returns a response to an Internet request.
         */
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        //Again why using?
        //Creating new StreamReader object named stream with value response.GetResponseStream()
        //.GetResponseStream() is WebResponse. method
        //When overridden in a descendant class, returns the data stream from the Internet resource.
        {
            direction = stream.ReadToEnd();
            //StreamReader.ReadToEnd Method
            //Reads all characters from the current position to the end of the stream.
        }
        //This is how the web page looks like
        //<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 89.71.166.131</body></html>
        int first = direction.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;//"Address: " it is 9 chars
        int last = direction.LastIndexOf("</body>");
        direction = direction.Substring(first, last - first);

        return direction;
    }
    void OnGUI()//Displaying it on the "screen"
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(80f, 50f, 100f, 25f), GetLocalIP());
        GUI.Label(new Rect(80f, 100f, 100f, 25f), GetPublicIP());
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, a machine may have more than one IP address, and the IP addresses can change over the course of time.

Comment: What is the exact question here? Which piece of code is confusing? "Explain the code" is not a very good question, especially with such a large code block.

Comment: Also, the IP address reported by checkip.dyndns.org is most likely not the IP address of your machine, but that of your router.

Comment: [Why "using"?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02.aspx) is for IDisposable objects

Comment: This might be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com...

Comment: Asking a DNS server who you are is a bit like asking your Mom what name she picked for you.  Everybody was born with the same name in networking, "localhost", aka 127.0.0.0

Comment: @DanPuzey, if the code works then yes this would be better on codereview, if not it will just get immediately closed there.

Answer (score 1):

"InterNetwork" means IPv4 see System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.

The problem as John Saunders said is that your computer may have more than one ip, for example you might have a wifi card connected to a network and an ethernet card connected to another network with an ethernet cable.

The second method : "GetPublicIP()", tries to connect to a remote server to find your ip.
Most houses with internet today use a router to connect to the Internet, this is why you can't get your external or public IP from your computer (your router has the public ip not your computer).

Comment: Well, it's not actually because of having a router that's the issue. The issue would be if the router was configured to use NAT or some other form of address mapping such that the internal and external IP addresses were different.

Comment: The purpose of a router is to route traffic from one subnet to another which is close to the destination.

Answer (score -1):

Well first off to be honest few people are going to read all your comments and answer them. That may be better suited for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/. They specialize in high level conversation and less on actual code problems.

But to answer one of your reoccurring questions. I see that you're often asking "why using". Well a using statement in C# automatically closes the connection when the code leaves the using statement. So you will often see it used with objects that are connection related (i.e. sqlconnection, or streamreader, etc.). Without a using the user would need to explicitly dispose of these objects to close the connection. Also as a side note, even if the code fails in the using statement, it will still dispose/close the object being used.

Comment: -1: no, this sort of question is not appropriate for [meta]. [meta] is for questions about [so].

Comment: Oh guess I was wrong, thanks for letting me know. I thought there was some stack exchange site dedicated to design questions/ learners.